# How to use qgraphicsitem_cast to cast an object of Base class, which inherits from QGraphicsItem, to its derived class?

Tags: c++, qt, casting, qgraphicsitem

I have three classes: `Base`, `Derived1`, and `Derived2`, where `Base` inherits from `QGraphicsItem`, and the other two classes inherit from `Base`. I am trying to cast them using `qgraphicsitem_cast` by overriding the `type()` method as mentioned in the Qt [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsitem.html#type). However, it does not work for `Base` class and returns `NULL`, whereas it works for `Derived1` and `Derived2` classes. I tried using the standard C++ way, `dynamic_cast`, and it works. How can I make it work for the `Base` class as well?

```
class Base : public QGraphicsItem {
public:
    Base(){}
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget = nullptr) override {}
    [[nodiscard]] QRectF boundingRect() const override {}
    enum {Type = QGraphicsItem::UserType + 1};
    [[nodiscard]] int type() const override { return Type; }
};

class Derived1 : public Base {
public:
    Derived1(){}
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget = nullptr) override {}
    [[nodiscard]] QRectF boundingRect() const override {}
    enum {Type = QGraphicsItem::UserType + 2};
    [[nodiscard]] int type() const override { return Type; }
};

class Derived2 : public Base {
public:
    Derived2(){}
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget = nullptr) override {}
    [[nodiscard]] QRectF boundingRect() const override {}
    enum {Type = QGraphicsItem::UserType + 3};
    [[nodiscard]] int type() const override { return Type; }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QGraphicsScene scene;
    QGraphicsView view(&scene);

    auto d1 = new Derived1;

    scene.addItem(d1);
    auto item = scene.items().first();

    auto castedItem1 = qgraphicsitem_cast<Base*>(item); // this line return NULL (Why?)
    auto castedItem2 = qgraphicsitem_cast<Derived1*>(item); // Work
    auto castedItem3 = dynamic_cast<Base*>(item); // Work!
    
    return QApplication::exec();
}
```

Comment: `qgraphicsitem_cast` doesn't understand inheritance hierarchy. It's basically `if (T::Type == ptr->type()) return static_cast<T*>(ptr); else return nullptr;` You can't really do better when all the runtime type information you have is a single integer.

Comment: Thanks @IgorTandetnik! I ended up using `dynamic_cast` instead of `qgraphicsitem_cast`, and that resolved the problem for me.